# OpenERP Users Customizing error

Tags: python, odoo

```
class res_users(osv.osv):

    def create(self, cr, uid, values, context=None):
        res_users_obj = self.pool.get('res.users')
        # res_users_obj.create(cr, uid, values)
        return res_users_obj.create(cr, uid, {
            'login': values['login'],
            'password': values['password'],
            'company_id': values['bpl_company_id'],
            'partner_id': values['officer_id'],
            'name': values['login']
            })

    # _inherit = "res.users"
    _name = "bpl.res.users"
    _columns = {
        'bpl_company_id':fields.many2one(
            'bpl.company.n.registration',
            'Company'),
        'bpl_estate_id':fields.many2one(
            'bpl.estate.n.registration',
            'Estate',
            help='Estate',
            domain="[('company_id','=',bpl_company_id)]"),
        'officer_id':fields.many2one(
            'bpl.officer',
            'User',
            domain="[('bpl_company_id','=',bpl_company_id)]"),
        'login': fields.char('Login', size=20),
        'password': fields.char('Password', size=20),
    }
res_users()
```

Above code shows my `res_user` class in `bpl` model.  I'm going to create users in my page and add record in `res_users` when I create users here.

Issue is now my users are creating in `res_users` table, but not in `bpl_res_users` table. When I press the `save` button it waits on the form view instead of navigating to the tree view.  No errors are showing in the console.

I uploaded my whole code [here @ GitHub](https://github.com/priyankahdp/openerp.git)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class res_users(osv.osv):

    def create(self, cr, uid, values, context=None):
        res_users_obj = self.pool.get('res.users')
        res_users_obj.create(cr, uid, {
            'login': values['login'],
            'password': values['password'],
            'company_id': values['bpl_company_id'],
            'partner_id': values['officer_id'],
            'name': values['login'],
        }, context=context)
        return super(res_users, self).create(cr, uid, values, context=context)

    # _inherit = "res.users"
    _name = "bpl.res.users"
    _columns = {
        'bpl_company_id':fields.many2one('bpl.company.n.registration', 'Company'),
        'bpl_estate_id':fields.many2one('bpl.estate.n.registration', 'Estate', help='Estate', domain="[('company_id','=',bpl_company_id)]"),
        'officer_id':fields.many2one('bpl.officer', 'User', domain="[('bpl_company_id','=',bpl_company_id)]"),
        'login': fields.char('Login', size=20),
        'password': fields.char('Password', size=20),
    }


res_users()
```

now its worked. its need to add super() method..now save records in both tables.

@Arya
thanks 4 ur advices

Answer (score 2):

A better solution is

```
class bpl_res_users(osv.osv):
    _inherits = {
        'res.users': 'user_id',
    }
    _name = "bpl.res.users"
    _columns = {
        'user_id': fields.many2one('res.users', required=True,
        string='Related User', ondelete='restrict',
        help='User-related data of the bpluser'),
        #define all other additional fields needed in your new model.
    }
bpl_res_users()
```

If you create a record in this bpl.res.users model, then a record will be automatically created in res.users. You can find a similar example in `base` module. check how res.users model is created.

Answer (score 1):

what r you doing in your code is

```
def create(self, cr, uid, values, context=None):
        res_users_obj = self.pool.get('res.users')
        # res_users_obj.create(cr, uid, values)
        return res_users_obj.create(cr, uid, {        'login': values['login'],
                                                      'password': values['password'],
                                                      'company_id': values['bpl_company_id'],
                                                      'partner_id': values['officer_id'],
                                                      'name': values['login']
                                                      })
```

res_users_obj = self.pool.get('res.users')
you pooling res.user object, instead of use

```
def create(self, cr, uid, values, context=None):

    return self.create(cr, uid, {        'login': values['login'],
                                                  'password': values['password'],
                                                  'company_id': values['bpl_company_id'],
                                                  'partner_id': values['officer_id'],
                                                  'name': values['login']
                                                  })
```

Comment: hi friend,
as per your code its trying to save records only in bpl_res_users table.but i need to save in res_users table also.because in logging time openerp checks username and password from res_users table.
please advice me for that.

when i try your answer it gave me error because in create function i included some fields name which are not in bpl_res_users model class

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
class bpl_res_users(osv.osv):

    _name = "bpl.res.users"
    _columns = {
        'bpl_company_id':fields.many2one('bpl.company.n.registration', 'Company'),
        'bpl_estate_id':fields.many2one('bpl.estate.n.registration', 'Estate', help='Estate', domain="[('company_id','=',bpl_company_id)]"),
        'officer_id':fields.many2one('bpl.officer', 'User', domain="[('bpl_company_id','=',bpl_company_id)]"),
        'login': fields.char('Login', size=20),
        'password': fields.char('Password', size=20),
    }

bpl_res_users()
```

Add related Views, Action and menu from xml. Update your module and check it.

Comment: Thanks i tried it friend.but not yet sorted it.
not records saves in bpl_res_users table.

Answer (score 0):

```
  def write_employee(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
       user_id=self.browse(cr,uid,ids,context=context).user_id
       if not user_id:
            for rec in self.browse(cr,uid, ids, context=context):
                  vals = { 'name':rec.name ,    'login':rec.work_email,'active':True }
                   user=self.pool.get('res.users').create( cr, uid, vals, context=context )
                   self.write( cr, SUPERUSER_ID, ids, {'user_id':user})
      return True
```

> try this and dnt forget to put **from openerp import SUPERUSER_ID** as header file